# How to make adb shell commands wrap single line to multiple lines by default?

Tags: adb, command-line

Let's say I have this long one-liner command:

```
am force-stop com.example.foo; am force-stop com.example.bar; am force-stop com.example.foo2 am force-stop com.example.bar2; am force-stop com.example.foo; am force-stop com.example.bar; ps|grep example
```

When I copy-paste into terminal, it doesn't wrap as multiple lines like ordinary terminal do, instead it keep single line:

[image]

As you can see, I can't view whole commands in single screen when the cursor move to the end by copy-paste OR press <kbd>End</kbd>. It only shows partial commands and not able to re-copy part of command easily.

Desired behavior:
[image]

Is it possible ? I learned that `COLUMNS=150` can increase the adb command width from 80 to 150, but still I can't found a way to achieve this.

Note that I don't want to add `\` manually which also not working when reuse the command:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is use `busybox sh`, but still I welcome any answer to achieve this in native way without busybox.